# Swift - Core Data - using the result of fetch with GroupBy

Tags: swift, core-data, group-by, nsdictionary, any

I couldn't find answer to this question, I checked all questions here.

Summary:
I don't know how to use the result(that I successfully get back) of .fetch() method with GroupBy. The fetch method result must have `.dictionaryResultType` because I am using `GroupBy`, otherwise the `GroupBy` would not work. I can see that fetch returns `[Any]`, so array of `Any`. However I try to cast/use/access this [Any] it fails.

My code:

```
  //Create new entity
    let timeLogEntity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "TimeLog", in: managedContext)!
    
    //sum up the duration column
    let keypathDuration = NSExpression(forKeyPath: "duration")
    let expression = NSExpression(forFunction: "sum:", arguments: [keypathDuration])
    let sumDesc = NSExpressionDescription()
    sumDesc.expression = expression
    sumDesc.name = "DurationSum"
    sumDesc.expressionResultType = .integer64AttributeType
    
    //Fetch request
    var timeLogFetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "TimeLog")
    
    //group by region
    timeLogFetchRequest.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false
    timeLogFetchRequest.propertiesToGroupBy = ["region"] 

   //sum of duration column
    timeLogFetchRequest.propertiesToFetch = [sumDesc, "region"]
    timeLogFetchRequest.resultType = .dictionaryResultType

   //it works only like this with [Any[\]
    var dailyFetchResult: [Any]?

do{
        dailyFetchResult = try managedContext.fetch(timeLogFetchRequest)
}catch...
```

So the fetch works and returns values, I just don't know how to use them, or convert them to anything usable dictionary, tuple, String and Int...

The result looks like this: `{DurationSum = 235; region = RegionName1}{DurationSum = 256; region = RegionName2}` etc

Thanks

Comment: The result is of course a dictionary when you set the resultType to `dictionaryResultType` and the dictionary is of type [String: Any]. You need to cast each value of the dictionary to the type of that attribute (sumDesc and region)

Comment: Thank you. That is what I am struggling with - making that cast...however I try it fails...

Comment: The result of the fetch is *an array* of dictionaries; try [[String:Any]].

Answer (score 1):

`(dailyFetchResult[0] as! [String:Any]).keys` , and `(dailyFetchResult[0] as! [String:Any]).values` did it. Thank you!